# TypeError: object of type 'instancemethod' has no len()

Tags: python, django

I'm finish cleaning my project. I remove not useful apps and codes then I arrange them. After this I encountered error

```
TypeError: object of type 'instancemethod' has no len()
```

so I change it to count() but I encountered error again

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'count'
```

Here is my code:

```
def budget(request):
    envelopes = Envelope.objects.filter(
         user=request.user).exclude_unallocated

    return render(request, 'budget.html', {
        'limit': account_limit(request, 15, envelopes),
    }


def account_limit(request, value, query):
    count_objects = len(query)

    //other codes here

    return result
```

I think I delete something here that's why I'm getting the error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You forgot to put ()

```
 envelopes = Envelope.objects.filter(user=request.user).exclude_unallocated()
```

Comment: I don't put () even before when it's working, but I will try your answer

Comment: OK thanks it's working now. I just notice that I must put () because I'm using it in len. Good catch up